# Symfony2: Bundle does not exist

Tags: symfony, bundle

I have this problem:

```
InvalidArgumentException: Bundle "DipUserBundle" does not exist or it is not enabled.
```

Btw I have two bundle inside Dip namespace. Both of them I made through console.

Please, is there someone who can help me.. here is my code!! Tnx

config.yml

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
    default:
    mappings:
        # ...
    DipBiznisBundle: ~
    DipUserBundle: ~
```

AppKernel.php

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel {
    public function registerBundles() {
        $bundles = array(
            ...
            new Dip\BiznisBundle\DipBiznisBundle(),
            new Dip\UserBundle\UserBundle(),
        );
```

routing.yml

```
homepage:
pattern: /
defaults: { _controller: DipUserBundle:Default:index }
```

UserBundle.php

```
<?php
    namespace Dip\UserBundle;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

    class UserBundle extends Bundle {
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem will be solved if you rename file and BiznisBundle to DipBiznisBundle and UserBundle to DipUserBundle... to avoid problems on future generate bundles using generate command and would define namespaces using slashes instead of backslashes....